# Proper use of a pronoun

Tags: word-choice, grammar

is i proper to say: we look forward to seeing you, X and Y? or or looking forward to seeing X, Y and you.

Answer (score 1):

One would not normally include an object pronoun in a list, where the names were simply separated with commas or an *and*.

In this instance I would say ***We look forward to seeing you, together with X and Y on ...***

To say *I look forward to seeing her, Michael and Jane on...* would risk interpretation as *her Michael, and Jane*. And *him, Michael and Jane* is equally awkward as it is not clear, when spoken quickly, that *him* and *Michael* are separate people.